# Is there a way to get the current position of an SKSpriteNode, that was placed in the Scene Editor, from code? - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Is there a way to get the current position of an SKSpriteNode that is in the Scene Editor?
I am trying to create a cannon feature in my game and I placed the cannon in the Scene Editor but I am coding the cannonball elements in a Swift file and I want to place the cannonball on-top of the cannon from the Swift file. Is there a way to get the position of an SKSpriteNode, that was placed in the Scene Editor, from code? Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I see a trend with your questions! 
what have you tried so far? what searches have you made? do you have any code to show? have you tried it and it's not working? Basically it looks like you are just asking someone to figure this out for you

Comment: As per Ron's comment, you need to do some good tutorials and learn how to read Apple's documentation so that you can discover what functions are available and how to do things. I personally recommend Ray Wenderlich tutorials as that's how I learnt, but there are plenty of others.

Comment: Sure thing! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your scene (code) you need to reference your cannon e.g.

```swift
   let myscene = GameScene(fileNamed:"WhateverYourSceneIsCalled")

   /// Once the file is referenced you can now reference objects from it. e.g.

   let myCannon = myscene.childNode(withName: "//YourCannon") as? SKNode // or whatever node type.
```

from there your canning is referenced in myCannon.

If you start a new game in Xcode, either for iOS or macOS, choose SpriteKit as the engine, and let it generate the template, it generates quite a simple example which is easy to reference.

To do that you:

1. Click on File > New > Project in Xcode
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkEIb.png
2. Choose game on whichever platform you prefer.[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0r78.png
3. Set your project up as normal
   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cud0C.png
4. And you'll see in the "GameScene.swift" or whichever language you chose, that's where they give an example of referencing a SKNode in the scene.
   [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbDXN.jpg

Hope this helps!